# Scraping Reddit in R with RedditExtractoR

Tags: r, web-scraping, reddit

I'm trying to scrape Reddit data (I'm pretty new to web scraping and half decent at R). The [RedditExtractor](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RedditExtractoR/RedditExtractoR.pdf) package has a nice function that does 90% of what I need, but it doesn't grab the "flair" associated with users who make comments. I'm trying to play around with the package's function but I'm a bit over my head.

There are examples of Reddit threads with flairs [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Christianity/comments/4m8qgv/i_love_orthodoxy_but_sometimes_their_political/). I think I'm looking for the text in these bits of XML:

```
<span class="flair flair-orthodox" title="Eastern Orthodox">Eastern Orthodox</span>
```

I've pasted the code from the `reddit_content()` function along with comments where I think the extra code should go, but I'm not quite sure where to go from here. At the moment the function returns a data frame with columns for the comment, time stamp, user, etc. I need it to also produce a comment with user flairs if they exist. Thanks in advance!

```
redd_content_flair <- function (URL, wait_time = 2) 
{
  if (is.null(URL) | length(URL) == 0 | !is.character(URL)) {
    stop("invalid URL parameter")
  }
  GetAttribute = function(node, feature) {
    Attribute = node$data[[feature]]
    replies = node$data$replies
    reply.nodes = if (is.list(replies)) 
      replies$data$children
    else NULL
    return(list(Attribute, lapply(reply.nodes, function(x) {
      GetAttribute(x, feature)
    })))
  }
  get.structure = function(node, depth = 0) {
    if (is.null(node)) {
      return(list())
    }
    filter = is.null(node$data$author)
    replies = node$data$replies
    reply.nodes = if (is.list(replies)) 
      replies$data$children
    else NULL
    return(list(paste0(filter, " ", depth), lapply(1:length(reply.nodes), 
                                                   function(x) get.structure(reply.nodes[[x]], paste0(depth, 
                                                                                                      "_", x)))))
  }
  data_extract = data.frame(id = numeric(), structure = character(), 
                            post_date = as.Date(character()), comm_date = as.Date(character()), 
                            num_comments = numeric(), subreddit = character(), upvote_prop = numeric(), 
                            post_score = numeric(), author = character(), user = character(), 
                            comment_score = numeric(), controversiality = numeric(), 
                            comment = character(), title = character(), post_text = character(), 
                            link = character(), domain = character(), 
                            #flair = character(),
                            URL = character())
  pb = utils::txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = length(URL), style = 3)
  for (i in seq(URL)) {
    if (!grepl("^https?://(.*)", URL[i])) 
      URL[i] = paste0("https://www.", gsub("^.*(reddit\\..*$)", 
                                           "\\1", URL[i]))
    if (!grepl("\\?ref=search_posts$", URL[i])) 
      URL[i] = paste0(gsub("/$", "", URL[i]), "/?ref=search_posts")
    X = paste0(gsub("\\?ref=search_posts$", "", URL[i]), 
               ".json?limit=500")
    raw_data = tryCatch(RJSONIO::fromJSON(readLines(X, warn = FALSE)), 
                        error = function(e) NULL)
    if (is.null(raw_data)) {
      Sys.sleep(min(1, wait_time))
      raw_data = tryCatch(RJSONIO::fromJSON(readLines(X, 
                                                      warn = FALSE)), error = function(e) NULL)
    }
    if (is.null(raw_data) == FALSE) {
      meta.node = raw_data[[1]]$data$children[[1]]$data
      main.node = raw_data[[2]]$data$children
      if (min(length(meta.node), length(main.node)) > 0) {
        structure = unlist(lapply(1:length(main.node), 
                                  function(x) get.structure(main.node[[x]], x)))
        TEMP = data.frame(id = NA, structure = gsub("FALSE ", 
                                                    "", structure[!grepl("TRUE", structure)]), 
                          post_date = format(as.Date(as.POSIXct(meta.node$created_utc, 
                                                                origin = "1970-01-01")), "%d-%m-%y"),
                          comm_date = format(as.Date(as.POSIXct(unlist(lapply(main.node, 
                                                                                                                                                          function(x) {
                                                                                                                                                            GetAttribute(x, "created_utc")
                                                                                                                                                          })), origin = "1970-01-01")), "%d-%m-%y"), 
                          num_comments = meta.node$num_comments,
                          subreddit = ifelse(is.null(meta.node$subreddit), 
                                                                                    "UNKNOWN", meta.node$subreddit), upvote_prop = meta.node$upvote_ratio, 
                          post_score = meta.node$score, author = meta.node$author, 
                          user = unlist(lapply(main.node, function(x) {
                            GetAttribute(x, "author")
                          })),
                          comment_score = unlist(lapply(main.node, 
                                                             function(x) {
                                                               GetAttribute(x, "score")
                                                             })),
                          controversiality = unlist(lapply(main.node, 
                                                                                                   function(x) {
                                                                                                     GetAttribute(x, "controversiality")
                                                                                                   })),
                          comment = unlist(lapply(main.node, function(x) {
                                                                                                     GetAttribute(x, "body")
                                                                                                   })),
                          title = meta.node$title, post_text = meta.node$selftext, 
                          link = meta.node$url, domain = meta.node$domain, 
                          #flair = unlist(lapply(main.node, function(x) {GetAttribute(x, "flair")})),
                          URL = URL[i], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        TEMP$id = 1:nrow(TEMP)
        if (dim(TEMP)[1] > 0 & dim(TEMP)[2] > 0) 
          data_extract = rbind(TEMP, data_extract)
        else print(paste("missed", i, ":", URL[i]))
      }
    }
    utils::setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
    Sys.sleep(min(2, wait_time))
  }
  close(pb)
  return(data_extract)
}
```

Edit: I'd also like to grab the URL for the "parent" comment, which looks like its in tags like

```
<p class="parent"><a name="d3t1p1r"></a></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to come up with an ad hoc solution. I'll post it here for posterity. The issue is the function as-is wasn't set up to handle NULL JSON values. It was a quick fix.

About midway down there are two `raw_data =` lines. You need to add the `nullValue = 'your null text'` argument to the `fromJSON` function. Then you can add whatever metadata you wanted to both the empty data frame and the TEMP data frame, using the same construction as elsewhere. In the function below I've added both the user's flair text and the ID of the parent comment.

(Note, the wonky indenting is from the original function...I've left it as is to prevent accidentally changing something.)

```
reddit.fixed <- function (URL, wait_time = 2) 
{
  if (is.null(URL) | length(URL) == 0 | !is.character(URL)) {
    stop("invalid URL parameter")
  }
  GetAttribute = function(node, feature) {
    Attribute = node$data[[feature]]
    replies = node$data$replies
    reply.nodes = if (is.list(replies)) 
      replies$data$children
    else NULL
    return(list(Attribute, lapply(reply.nodes, function(x) {
      GetAttribute(x, feature)
    })))
  }
  get.structure = function(node, depth = 0) {
    if (is.null(node)) {
      return(list())
    }
    filter = is.null(node$data$author)
    replies = node$data$replies
    reply.nodes = if (is.list(replies)) 
      replies$data$children
    else NULL
    return(list(paste0(filter, " ", depth), lapply(1:length(reply.nodes), 
                                                   function(x) get.structure(reply.nodes[[x]], paste0(depth, 
                                                                                                      "_", x)))))
  }
  data_extract = data.frame(id = numeric(), structure = character(), 
                            post_date = as.Date(character()), comm_date = as.Date(character()), 
                            num_comments = numeric(), subreddit = character(), upvote_prop = numeric(), 
                            post_score = numeric(), author = character(), user = character(), 
                            comment_score = numeric(), controversiality = numeric(), 
                            comment = character(), title = character(), post_text = character(), 
                            link = character(), domain = character(), URL = character(), flair = character(), parent = character())
  pb = utils::txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = length(URL), style = 3)
  for (i in seq(URL)) {
    if (!grepl("^https?://(.*)", URL[i])) 
      URL[i] = paste0("https://www.", gsub("^.*(reddit\\..*$)", 
                                           "\\1", URL[i]))
    if (!grepl("\\?ref=search_posts$", URL[i])) 
      URL[i] = paste0(gsub("/$", "", URL[i]), "/?ref=search_posts")
    X = paste0(gsub("\\?ref=search_posts$", "", URL[i]), 
               ".json?limit=500")
    raw_data = tryCatch(RJSONIO::fromJSON(readLines(X, warn = FALSE), nullValue = "none"), 
                        error = function(e) NULL)
    if (is.null(raw_data)) {
      Sys.sleep(min(1, wait_time))
      raw_data = tryCatch(RJSONIO::fromJSON(readLines(X, 
                                                      warn = FALSE), nullValue = "none"), error = function(e) NULL)
    }
    if (is.null(raw_data) == FALSE) {
      meta.node = raw_data[[1]]$data$children[[1]]$data
      main.node = raw_data[[2]]$data$children
      if (min(length(meta.node), length(main.node)) > 0) {
        structure = unlist(lapply(1:length(main.node), 
                                  function(x) get.structure(main.node[[x]], x)))
        TEMP = data.frame(id = NA, structure = gsub("FALSE ", 
                                                    "", structure[!grepl("TRUE", structure)]), 
                          post_date = format(as.Date(as.POSIXct(meta.node$created_utc, 
                                                                origin = "1970-01-01")), "%d-%m-%y"), comm_date = format(as.Date(as.POSIXct(unlist(lapply(main.node, 
                                                                                                                                                          function(x) {
                                                                                                                                                            GetAttribute(x, "created_utc")
                                                                                                                                                          })), origin = "1970-01-01")), "%d-%m-%y"), 
                          num_comments = meta.node$num_comments, subreddit = ifelse(is.null(meta.node$subreddit), 
                                                                                    "UNKNOWN", meta.node$subreddit), upvote_prop = meta.node$upvote_ratio, 
                          post_score = meta.node$score, author = meta.node$author, 
                          user = unlist(lapply(main.node, function(x) {
                            GetAttribute(x, "author")
                          })), comment_score = unlist(lapply(main.node, 
                                                             function(x) {
                                                               GetAttribute(x, "score")
                                                             })), controversiality = unlist(lapply(main.node, 
                                                                                                   function(x) {
                                                                                                     GetAttribute(x, "controversiality")
                                                                                                   })), comment = unlist(lapply(main.node, function(x) {
                                                                                                     GetAttribute(x, "body")
                                                                                                   })), title = meta.node$title, post_text = meta.node$selftext, 
                          link = meta.node$url, domain = meta.node$domain, 
                          URL = URL[i], 
                          flair = unlist(lapply(main.node, function(x) {
                            GetAttribute(x, "author_flair_text")
                          })),
                          parent = unlist(lapply(main.node, function(x) {GetAttribute(x, "parent_id")})),
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        TEMP$id = 1:nrow(TEMP)
        if (dim(TEMP)[1] > 0 & dim(TEMP)[2] > 0) 
          data_extract = rbind(TEMP, data_extract)
        else print(paste("missed", i, ":", URL[i]))
      }
    }
    utils::setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
    Sys.sleep(min(2, wait_time))
  }
  close(pb)
  return(data_extract)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, got your message a little late, but it looks like you've figured it out already. Once you add `nullValue = "some text"` to `raw_data` you can add other attributes found under `main.node` or `meta.node`. So to fetch flair for a comment, use 
`unlist(lapply(main.node, function(x){GetAttribute(x,"author_flair_text")}))`
or 
`unlist(lapply(main.node, function(x){GetAttribute(x,"author_flair_css_class")}))`
or `meta.node$author_flair_text` and 
`meta.node$author_flair_css_class` to get the thread flair. I will be looking to add these to the next release of the package.