# Using reddit API to scrape posts from a specific time period in RStudio

Tags: r

I'm trying to scrape data from r/coding for a topic modelling and sentiment analysis using RStudio. I cannot return observations more than 100 and when I specify a time range I do not return any observations.

```
# Install required packages

    install.packages("jsonlite")
    install.packages("tidyverse")
    install.packages("httr")

# Load required libraries

    library(jsonlite)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(httr)

# Set your Reddit app credentials

    client_id <- ""
    client_secret <- ""
    username <- ""
    password <- ""

# Authenticate and obtain an access token

    token_url <- "https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token"
    response <- POST(token_url,
                 body = list(
                   grant_type = "password",
                   username = username,
                   password = password
                 ),
                 add_headers(
                   "User-Agent" = "YOUR_USER_AGENT"
                 ),
                 authenticate(client_id, client_secret),
                 encode = "form"
    )

# Parse the access token from the response

    access_token <- content(response)$access_token

# Use the access token to make API requests

    all_posts <- data.frame()

# Define the time frame

    start_time <- as.POSIXct("2022-11-01", tz = "UTC")
    end_time <- Sys.time()

# Retrieve posts until the end of the time frame

    after <- ""
    all_posts <- data.frame()
    
    repeat {
      response <- GET(
        "https://www.reddit.com/r/coding/new/.json",
        query = list(after = after),
        add_headers(
          "User-Agent" = "YOUR_USER_AGENT"
        )
      )
    
      if (http_type(response) != "application/json") {
        stop("Error: Failed to retrieve posts from Reddit API.")
      }
    
      data <- content(response)$data
      posts <- data$children$data
    
      if (length(posts) == 0) {
        break
      }
    
      if (length(all_posts) == 0) {
        all_posts <- posts
      } else {
        all_posts <- rbind(all_posts, posts)
      }
    
      last_post_time <- as.POSIXct(posts[length(posts)]$created_utc, origin = "1970-01-01", tz =     "UTC")
      if (any(is.na(last_post_time)) || any(is.na(start_time)) || any(last_post_time < start_time)) {
        break
      }
    
      after <- posts[length(posts)]$name
      Sys.sleep(2)  # Pause for 2 seconds between API calls to comply with Reddit API guidelines
    }

# Convert the created_utc to a timestamp

    all_posts$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(all_posts$created_utc, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")

# Filter posts based on the desired time frame

    filtered_posts <- all_posts[all_posts$timestamp >= start_time & all_posts$timestamp <= end_time, ]

# Display the filtered posts

    print(filtered_posts[, c("ups", "title", "subreddit", "url", "selftext", "created")])
```

Comment: Maybe this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602908/scraping-reddit-in-r-with-redditextractor

Comment: Hello, bear in mind that in the last week (~30/6) Reddit changed their API policy quite substantially (to the loud annoyance of many users).  If you're following a guide or using an older package you may well get unexpected results.